# Displaying custom field of product variations on Woocommerce cart

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, product-variations

In Woocommerce, I successfully added a custom field for product variations within the backend. Saving its input data and displaying it within the `add-to-cart/variation.php` works as well.

But what about displaying the value of this field within the `cart.php`?

I only found solutions of this for regular product items but not for product variations. Here's what I have so far within my functions.php file:

```
//Display Fields in admin on product edit screen
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'woo_variable_fields', 10, 3 );

//Save variation fields values
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_fields', 10, 2 );

// Create new fields for variations
function woo_variable_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {

echo '<div class="variation-custom-fields">';

  // Text Field
  woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
      'id'          => '_text_field['. $loop .']', 
      'label'       => __( 'additional fees (e.g. monthly fee)', 'woocommerce' ), 
      'placeholder' => '',
      //'desc_tip'    => true,
      'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-first',
      //'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
      'value'       => get_post_meta($variation->ID, '_text_field', true)
    )
  );

echo "</div>"; 

}

/** Save new fields for variations */
function save_variation_fields( $variation_id, $i) {

// Text Field
$text_field = stripslashes( $_POST['_text_field'][$i] );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
}

// Custom Product Variation
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_load_variation_settings_products_fields' );

function custom_load_variation_settings_products_fields( $variations )    { 
$variations['variation_custom_field'] = get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], '_text_field', true );  
return $variations;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display this custom field in cart items, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_field_as_item_data', 20, 2 );
function display_custom_field_as_item_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    if( $value = get_post_meta( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), '_text_field', true ) ){
        $cart_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Additional Monthly Fee', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => sanitize_text_field( $value )
        );
    }
    return $cart_data;
}
```

It will work as well inall products post type and Product variations too in cart and checkout pages.

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec!
This is great and works so far. Is there any chance to display the value of this in a certain spot within the cart.php, like below the total price on the right? I tried out something like `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_text_field', true );` but that did not return anything.

`echo get_post_meta( $_product->variation_id, ‘_text_field’, true );` neither..

Comment: @Bradley as this is a cart item, it need to stay in the cart item loop dynamic table part (as you can have multiple items in cart). You could alter the table overriding the template cart.php staying inside the foreach loop… The working code is: `get_post_meta( $_product->get_id(), '_text_field', true );` for all product types even product variations…

Comment: finally! I now override the cart.php within the child theme and it's displaying the custom field's value right where I want it, although of course the additional value is not multiplied appropriate to the items quantity. But for now this brings me a big step closer to where I wanted it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I now disabled the quantity function on this product type since quantity did not make sense in this case anyway. One last question though. Is there a way to display the value of the field within the purchase email?

Comment: Hm, ist there a hook like the one you provided above to display the field's value right below the product price / total of each item within cart/checkout etc.?

Comment: done! See new specified question here
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383136/woocommerce-displaying-custom-field-of-product-variations-within-orders-and-ema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383136/woocommerce-displaying-custom-field-of-product-variations-within-orders-and-ema)